# Pass command line arguments from Excel hyperlink

Tags: excel, vba, command-line

I want to execute a complex command-line command when I **click a cell in excel**, a hyperlink cell. I've tried everything but I can't get it to work.

1. You can right-click and choose Hyperlink but the dialog doesn't support complex arguments (arguments with double quotes). You simply get an error "Invalid link".
2. You can use the `=HYPERLINK()` formula but that doesn't support arguments at all. Only web URLs are executed, such as `mailto:` and `callto:`. URLs can have parameters passed with `&arg=value` but that's no good for command-line arguments.

I don't know what else to try, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a `Shell` command with the following syntax

e.g.

```
Sub RunCalculator()
    Dim ret as Double 'Optional
    ret = Shell("C:\Windows\System32\Calc.exe")
    MsgBox(ret)   ' in case you are interested in the return value
End Sub
```

**To execute when clicking a cell:**

You need to put your code in a macro that's invoked from the `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event which you can get by using the dropdown in the VBE when you open the code for the worksheet in the editor.

**Unrelated side note:** The name reminds of the times when one used the DOS shell

Comment: As a possible enhancement, if you use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event instead, the user interaction should be more natural. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15266401/262789) for more info.