# Excel hyperlink cell to textbox

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I am trying to manually put a hyperlink in a cell, pointing to a textbox. Internet search was fruitless.

In the "add hyperlink" dialog window I tried writing the name of the textbox ("TextBox1") in the "type of cell reference" window, but got "Reference not valid".

There is also no "TextBox1" under the "defined names" in the same window.

My two questions:

- Is it possible for a textbox to be the target of a hyperlink in Excel?
- Is it possible to do it without VBA?

Other people will be using the workbook and creating those hyperlinks, so the simplest solution is best.

Comment: well in vba it would be really easy. just reset focus on click event. This is probably in one line fo code

Comment: well. would you care to write that "one line of code" ?

Answer (score 0):

to answer your two questions:

1) Yes, it is possible
2) no, you need VBA or Need to perform it manually. I have no idea how it should work with just formulas.

Comment: Would you care to explain 1) ?

Comment: See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15266401/262789) to _Excel-Hyperlink with a search function_ for a possible solution. If you use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` VBA event. Your VBA event handler can change the focus to the specified text box.